# Pip install failing in Windows

Tags: python

I cannot install python packages locally on my work windows machine.  Inside powershell I have tried

```
py -m pip install pandas
```

only to get the following errors:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /simple/pandas/

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/selenium/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1006)'))) - skipping

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for selenium

I would use something like conda, but my company will not permit conda.  How can I download packages via pip?

Comment: Is it a company computer and do you have an IT department? More than likely that is a prohibited activity on the computer and you need to get with them to allow it or get packages approved by them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/ pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

First ensure `pip` is up to date, because SSL errors in pip are usually an indicator of an outdated pip version.

`py -m pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/ --upgrade pip`